# Using SAMtools and storing outputs for a large number of files

Tags: bash, loops, shell, unix, samtools

I've got 500+ files that I need to change from .bam to .sam so am trying to use samtools. I've done some looking on here and found this answer ([Changing file paths outputs within a loop, in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509252/changing-file-paths-outputs-within-a-loop-in-a-shell-script)) and modified it to fit my work:

```
input_files="/scratch/spectre/h/homeTCGA_Data/*.bam"
output_files="/scratch/spectre/h/home/Data_Sam"
for i in $input_files 
do
tmp=$(i/scratch/spectre/h/home/Data_Sam) 
samtools view -h $i > $(tmp/.bam/.sam)
done
```

I'm a complete novice at this so I'm assuming that I've made an obvious mistake somewhere. The error I'm getting with this is that the directory 'Data_Sam' doesn't exist along with 'ambiguous redirect'. I've checked and it definitely does exist in scratch. I've also tried this in case I'm way over complicating things:

```
 for i in `ls ${/scratch/spectre/h/home/Data/}/*.bam`
 do
 samtools view -h <$i >${/scratch/spectre/h/home/Data_Sam}/$i.sam
 done
```

For this I'm getting the error 'bad substitution' for ${/scratch/spectre/h/home/Data/}/*.bam`.

I've also tried the following and get the error 'bad substitution':

```
for i in "ls ${/scratch/spectre/h/home/Data/}/*.bam";
do filename "${i%%.*}";
samtools view $i ${filename}.sam;
done
```

Is there any way that I can loop over my 500+ files, change them from bam to sam and store them somewhere new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first attempt, the syntax you are looking for string substitution is `${parameter/pattern/string}` where *parameter* gets expanded and in the result the longest match of *pattern* gets substituted with *string*. Note that this syntax uses curly braces, not parentheses (see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in the Bash manual).

I think this is what you were trying to do:

```
input_files="/scratch/spectre/h/home/Data/*.bam"
for i in $input_files 
do
    tmp=${i/Data/Data_Sam}                 # replace 'Data' with 'Data_Sam'
    samtools view -h $i > ${tmp/.bam/.sam} # replace '.bam' with '.sam'
done
```

With small changes you could easily make it more robust against file names containing spaces or containing ".bam" somewhere in the middle:

```
input_files="/scratch/spectre/h/home/Data/*.bam"
for i in $input_files 
do
    tmp="${i/Data/Data_Sam}"
    samtools view -h "$i" > "${tmp/%.bam/.sam}"
done
```